# как через js jQuery сделать индикаторы, которые правильно показывали б температуру и менялись в зависимости от условия

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, progress-bar

[image: сайт погоды]

Я хочу создать эти индикаторы голубые на `css`.
И вообще, как сделать так чтобы они работали в зависимости от того какая погода? Чтобы менялся размер индикатора. Это json ?
Помогите пожалуйста

Comment: у вас сайт резиновый или статика?

Comment: Zurb Foundation

Comment: Как вы получаете погоду?

Comment: json   

OpenWeatherMap.org        API

Comment: @Valentyn тогда получайте json и основываясь на нем рисуйте шкалу у блока. это можно реализовать с помощью метода jquery `animate()`.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если особо не напрягаться приблизительный концепт:

```js
$('.indicator').each(function() {
  var currentHeight = $(this).height();
  var newHeight = $(this).data('current'); //здесь происходит просчет заданной цифры температуры
  var totalHeight = (currentHeight + newHeight) * 10; //Умножение добавляем для красоты полоски 
  $(this).css('height', totalHeight);
  $(this).append('<div class="curren-temperature"></div>').find(".curren-temperature").text(totalHeight / 10) //при выводе температуры убираем умножение, которое добавляло красоту.
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: auto;
  background: #000217;
}
.indicator-list {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: auto;
  color: #fff;
}
.indicator {
  background: #00BFF5;
  width: 30px;
  height: 0;
  margin: 10px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
.curren-temperature {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -20px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">

  <ul class="indicator-list">
    <li class="indicator" data-current="15">
      <!--в data-current задаем наши градусы -->
      <li class="indicator" data-current="18">
        <li class="indicator" data-current="20">
          <li class="indicator" data-current="32">
  </ul>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно менять значение ползунка в зависимости от переменной температуры.
Как это будет происходить зависит от того, как устанавливается/получается эта переменная. Например, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759987/listening-for-variable-changes-in-javascript-or-jquery и https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5860218/javascript-event-listener-for-changes-in-an-object-variable

Можно сделать и так: сделать hidden элемент на странице, куда значением идет температура. Затем:

```
$('#hiddenelem').change(function()
{
   // меняем размер индикатора
});
```

Для индикаторов:
http://www.jqueryrain.com/demo/jquery-range-slider/
Или это может быть рисунок индикатора, растягивающийся по высоте по значению...